# Проблема по базе данных sqlite (Flask)

Tags: python, база-данных, flask

У меня та же самая проблема по базе данных sqlite (Flask) и ошибка такая же, когда в консоли пишу

```
>>> from app import db
>>> db.create_all()
```

Код:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///blog.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Article(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    intro = db.Column(db.String(300), nullable=False)
    text = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Article %r>' % self.id

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/about')
def hello():
    return render_template('about.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Какая "такая же"? Вы не привели в вопросе собственно ошибку. Добавьте ошибку в вопрос - вы можете его редактировать

Comment: >>> from app import db
>>> db.create_all() - если писать в командной строке python, a не в скрипте, я это имела ввиду
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Flaskblog\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\extension.py", line 884, in create_all     
    self._call_for_binds(bind_key, "create_all")
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Flaskblog\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\extension.py", line 855, in _call_for_binds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша проблема может быть связана с необходимостью импортировать экземпляр объекта **`app**` из вашего скрипта Flask перед вызовом `db.create_all()`. Попробуйте добавить эту строку кода перед вызовом `db.create_all()`:

```
from app import app
```

Если это не поможет, попробуйте проверить, что путь к вашей базе данных SQLite задан корректно в строке конфигурации `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']`.

Comment: Спасибо! Так работает.

Answer (score 0):

База данных по этому коду все-таки создается, если не писать в консоли указанные команды, а в терминале (тип Command Prompt в PyCharm) набрать: python app.py и запустить : Running on [http://127.0.0.1:5000.После](http://127.0.0.1:5000.%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5) этого нужно посмотреть папку instance и там будет файл blog.db.